# Ios Archiving takes long time

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

Archiving takes about 20 minutes to complete (My game is written in cocos2d-x (c++) so there are static libraries with about 1000 cpp files). Can I somehow tell xcode not to recompile them every time I want to archive?

Comment: Check your header file dependencies.  Use function prototypes when possible.

Comment: When you archive, you really do want a complete, clean build.

Comment: I use function prototypes all the time. Normally when you build the files that were not modified do not recompile. But when archiving they do